# Hide custom menu when when no menu selected

Tags: menus, customization

The title might not a 100%, feel free to correct...

I'm building a custom theme that has a couple of costume theme locations for menus (1 main menu, 1 footer menu, 1 "Follow Live" button). These are specified as a Theme Location in the Menu's panel.

I'm having an issue with the footer menu: when that theme location does not have a menu selected, it falls back to displaying all pages. I'd like it to not display anything when it's not linked to a menu.

The menu is defined in functions.php like this:

```
function add_footer() {
register_nav_menus(
    array('footer-menu' => __('Footer Navigation'),));} 
add_action('init', 'add_footer');
```

And it's displayed on the page like this:

```
    <?php
         wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'footer-menu', 
        'menu_class' => 'false', 
        'container' => 'false', 
        'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 
        ));?>
```

I've tried removing the `fallback_cf`option but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `fallback_cb` to `false`, it will not show anything if the menu doesn't exist. [The codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) does a pretty great job of detailing the parameters of `wp_nav_menu()`, it's DEFINITELY worth a read.